# Object is all nil in Rails 4+?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, models

I have a 'landing.html.erb' under a folder 'Welcome' in my Views. In the WelcomeController, I have the following:

```
def landing
@quiz = Quiz.new
end
```

to create a new Quiz. When the User clicks the create button,

```
def create
@quiz = current_user.quiz.build(quiz_params)
if @quiz.save
  flash[:success] = "Updated"
  redirect_to @quiz
else
  render 'new'
 end
end

def quiz_params
 params.require(:quiz).permit(:q1)
end
```

is the code I have for the QuizzesController. However, this gives the error:

```
undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
```

specifically at the line

```
@quiz = current_user.quiz.build(quiz_params)
```

I ran the rails console and typed Quiz.new and it displayed every field as 'nil' and I'm not entirely sure what I need to modify and would appreciate guidance.

The Quiz model belongs_to User.
The User has_one Quiz.

Thank you very much.

Comment: you need to use current_user.build_quiz(quiz_params), if having has_one association.

Comment: If you don't mind, I will put the detailed answer.

Comment: @power No problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I am assuming you are having has_one association among user and quiz.
So for build the associated object you need to use the following code.

```
current_user.build_quiz(quiz_params)
```

This will build the quiz object with the user_id field contains the id of the current user and other fields according to quiz_params.